# Excel VBA- "Object does not support this property or method" when activating and adding a value to a cell

Tags: excel, collections, vba

I get "Object doesn't support this property or method" when using this code

```
Windows(formatBook).Worksheets(2).Range("B4").Value = title
```

I just want to put a value on Range B4 of the second sheet of the book in which the sheet name changes

I tried breaking down the code to

```
Windows(formatBook).Activate
Worksheets(2).Activate
Range("B4").Activate
ActiveCell.Value = title
```

and it works. Why did it give me the error on the first code and how do I shorten my code?

Comment: try it as `Workbooks(formatBook).Worksheets(2).Range("B4").Value = title`

Comment: Works! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the Windows collection and Workbooks collection share many properties and methods, they are not completely interchangeable. In this case you need Workbooks.

```
Workbooks(formatBook).Worksheets(2).Range("B4").Value = title
```